# Make the Stack Overflow chat more prominently linked

Tags: discussion, feature-request, chat, hyperlinks

Recently I have noticed that not many people know about the existence of the Stack Overflow chat, among them many seasoned (10k+ rep) users. Stack Overflow Chat is just something where you end up by happenstance after using the site for some years. This is unfortunate, as I consider the lively discussion in the chats, especially in the famous [Python room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6/python) to nicely complement the QA site.

Now, the chat is not exactly prominently advertised on the Stack Overflow; the only link being the tiny one in the bottom footer where it is hidden among the usual boring legal information.

Thus comes a very simple feature suggestion, with possibly very profound impact: Could a link to the chat be placed into the top toolbar, possibly next to the **Ask Question**?

Comment: It's also linked next to the site name in the site switcher (the big Stack Exchange button in the top bar).

Comment: Indeed, that one I hadn't noticed before ;)

Comment: Pretty sure plenty of seasoned SO users choose not to know about it.

Comment: I can't seem to find the chat link. And @animuson, the link is next to the Stack Exchange button? I must be blind. :) ...Ah, now I see, it is in the popup as a link on the right. Still, not very prominent. I think a link at the bottom of the question to bring to chat would be great or as an option in the Share dialog.

Comment: @IAbstract I never noticed it there until somebody pointed it out in a related topic. So you're not the only one who needed help spotting it...

Comment: I am still finding it challenging getting to the chat room as when I click on chat.stackoverflow.com all I get are 45 pages x 20 rooms = 900 rooms. I don't want to trawl via the 45 pages of list to get to the chat room. It would have been nicer if there was an absolute link that would lead you to that chat room.

Looking forward to people who might guide the same.

Comment: I know of the chat, and have for quite a while, but i don't see any value in it other than for long comment discussions, which is why I don't use it other than for long comment discussions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Though at first it might seem wise to improve the visibility of chat I believe it was by design that it is not easy to find (I too pondered why it was not prominently shown on the site), simply put, the creators/maintainers do not want the site's main purpose be degraded:

> Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional and enthusiast programmers. This site is all about getting answers. It's not a discussion forum. There's no chit-chat. [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Think of Stack Overflow (and Stack Exchange sites in general) as a response to the chat phenomenon (an anti-chat if you will), by creating a better system, one that rewards desired behaviors and punishes others it educates the user, avoids excessive redundancy, helps countless answer seekers throughout time instead of just the people in the chat room at that moment and thus improves future contributions (or they stop using the site, or users get banned eventually for failure to follow the rules/bad score.

By allowing chat, SO has opened the floodgates to the very thing they wish to avoid, however if chat is barely used and not prominent then perhaps it becomes just a place to hang out with some friends or people with similar interests. Making chat more prominent might influence new users to ask good questions in the chatroom (which is not good). This also signals to the rest of the community that yes, we do have chat, but no, we don't really want you to use it for Q&A, which is probably best.

Comment: I agree, it's not really related to Q&A

Comment: Somewhat ironic, what with the experiments in "Documentation" and a TV channel that have sucked up all the dev time of late.

Answer (score 0):

Highlighting answer-specific chats would get extended discussions out of the posts - which seems like the intent.  Making answer-specific chat more prominent would seem to serve that intent.

Answer-specific chats have the potential for extending the collaboration of interested parties - and solving the problems  - and that seems to be the bigger SO objective.  There's already a mechanism to keep chats from expiring w/o bookmarking the things - that would be good here, I think.

I think making the chat initially available - but not getting mixed up in the thread of comments, as currently happens, would encourage users to comment when appropriate, or shoot off a into the chat as needed.  A separation of concerns is needed here :-)

Question-wide chats - as opposed to answer-specific chats - seem counterproductive to the site's intent.  They can prevent the often very good clarifying comments for showing on the question.  A lot of very highly rated questions have some really good long chains of comments.  Don't need to hurt that.

The more tag-oriented or open chats seem to dilute the purpose far more than answer chats, and I agree with @un5t0ppab13 on that point.  Its also kind of hard (or at least non-obvious) to keep a consistent thread going when so many voices are chiming in.  The answer-specific chats don't suffer on that front.

As it stands, relative newbs, like myself, have failed to get back into a chat that has been started on a comment thread.  Buttonizing a virtual chat for an answer might help - maybe with a message count, or unread message count, or referencing-me-unread-message count?  Or maybe with some kind of @abstract + "...in chat" of the last message that fits one of those categories.