# Do chat room links belong in tag wikis?

Tags: discussion, chat, tag-wiki

I just got an edit review for a tag wiki change removing a `chat.stackoverflow.com` link from a tag wiki. [This answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/277072/27358) seems to suggest that chat rooms are Considered Harmful and/or only for Secret Masters of SO, so possibly the link was removed on that basis? I'll be honest, I've only just become barely aware of the existence of chat rooms here, and I've certainly never chatted in one, so I don't really know what they're for or whether they're appropriate here. I hit "skip" in this case, but next time, should I approve or reject the edit?

Comment: I guess it's considered fine as long as the chatroom's title doesn't contain the name of any of my organs.

Comment: Can you link to the edit review? I'm not really sure what the context is here.

Comment: I already skipped it, so it's gone. And I can't remember offhand what the tag was -- not one I was familiar with. Is there a way to get an alphabetical list of chatrooms?