# Chat link not appearing in the footer

Tags: discussion, bug

Shouldn't there be a link to chat in the footer of the Stack Overflow page?

Is there any special reason why it doesn't appear, despite it being mentioned to be there?

---

Background:

I was trying to get more familiar with Stack Overflow; I was the checking my privileges and one of them is to talk in chat. 
It took me a while to actually find the link to chat, as it just between help and logout in the menu switcher (at the right of the upper bar). I actually needed to check the privilege page to find it.
And then I got confused, as it there says:

> There is a link to chat in the footer of every page, as well as in the Stack Exchange site switcher menu (top left corner of the page).

This question, [Make the Stack Overflow chat more prominently linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255993/make-the-stack-overflow-chat-more-prominently-linked), has a discussion about it, but the link is definitely not there. However it is there in another SE site: TeX.

Maybe it was decided to make the exposure even less, but then a update in the description of the privileges would be good.